# JavaFx Line Chart Legend Symbol

Tags: css, javafx

I am trying to draw line chart without symbol which I managed to do it. Then I want to set the legend symbol as a line instead of symbol. So I try to use

> -fx-shape: "M0,0 l10,0";

to draw a line but nothing is shown. Then I try to draw a rectange using

> -fx-shape: "M1,0 L5,0 L15,0 L1,1 Z";

But instead of rectangle it gives me a square just like the second legend symbol.

```
*{
  -line-0: #191970;
  -line-1: #e9967a;
  -line-2: #f0e68c;
  -line-3: #dda0dd;
  -line-4: #0181e2;
  -line-5: #2f357f;

  -fx-create-symbols: false;
}

.default-color0.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: -line-0;  }
.default-color1.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: -line-1; }
.default-color2.chart-series-line { -fx-stroke: -line-2; }

.default-color0.chart-line-symbol {  /*solid circle*/ 
    -fx-background-color: -line-0;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-shape: "M0,0 l10,0";
}
.default-color1.chart-line-symbol { /* solid square */
    -fx-background-color: -line-1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}
.default-color2.chart-line-symbol { /* solid diamond */
    -fx-background-color: -line-2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-padding: 7px 5px 7px 5px;
    -fx-shape: "M5,0 L10,9 L5,18 L0,9 Z";
}
.default-color3.chart-line-symbol { /* cross */
    -fx-background-color: #0181e2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-shape: "M2,0 L5,4 L8,0 L10,0 L10,2 L6,5 L10,8 L10,10 L8,10 L5,6 L2,
    10 L0,10 L0,8 L4,5 L0,2 L0,0 Z";
}
.default-color4.chart-line-symbol { /* solid triangle */
    -fx-background-color: #2f357f;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-shape: "M5,0 L10,8 L0,8 Z";
}
```

[image]

How can I show a line in legend symbol?

Comment: I think you are looking for `chart-legend-item-symbol`. `chart-line-symbol` are the symbols for data points on the line, but since you set `-fx-create-symbols` to false those are not shown.

Comment: But as you see, Portfolio 2 and Portfolio 3 still showing the legend symbol. If I use "-fx-shape: "M1,0 L5,0 L15,0 L1,1 Z";" it will show a square